# Firebase only with an icon empty push

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

every day in the morning on the app comes an empty firebase push)
I checked the backend, the backend in the morning does not send anything.
Maybe someone has an idea of ​​what can be.

Comment: Did you check your firebase account, there may be test push configured. please check it also

Comment: checked the firebase account there everything is fine